# Combine multiple disks to one 'big' disk on my external HDD

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, external-hard-drive

I run into a problem with my external HDD, i used it for backups but when i reinstalled windows (and forgot to remove the HDD) my HDD got wiped. After the wipe suddenly my HDD split itself into multiple Disks.

I would like to bring it back to one disk, just like it was when i bought it.

Can anyone help me out, or give me some tips on how to achieve this?

Here is an image of the partitions, if you need any extra details of information let me know and i will post it!

Disk management:

[image]

Comment: I could not add an decent image because i need at least 10 rep for that, sorry!

Comment: I hope that you aren't interested in recovering any of the data that was previous on that drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that the drive appears as Unallocated space, so you have to [partition and format](http://wdc.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3865/) it first, including assigning of a drive letter, and after that you can follow the steps on how to merge all of them (since there won't be any data on the two small partitions) by following the steps in the solution of [this Microsoft discussion](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/19b60bc3-86a2-45d1-b2b5-16f9f3671a2b/how-to-merge-partitions-in-windows-7-).

Hope this helps and let me know how it went. :)

Comment: Thanks for replying! I am on it! i will let you know if it worked out!

Comment: Your first link doesn't work (blank page) in Firefox 48.0.1.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.